# jQuery: how do I return true if any checkbox is selected in an array of checkboxes?

Tags: jquery

my checkboxs each look like this:

```
<input id="bulk_selected_" name="bulk_selected[]" type="checkbox" value="159">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return jQuery('[name="bulk_selected[]"]:checked').size()
```

If none are checked, then it will return `0` (a false value) otherwise it will return a positive number (which will be true).

Comment: 2 things here...you should provide an element selector when using an attribute one to narrow it down some, also `.size()` is just a wrapper for `.length`....not sure why they added it really :)

Comment: For any other attribute selector that's true, but "name" selectors are special and short cut to document.getElementsByName() which is far more specific than document.getElementsByTagName().

See here for more info http://github.com/jeresig/sizzle/blob/master/sizzle.js#L293

Answer (score 4):

Use an [attribute-equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) and [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/), like this:

```
return $("input[name='bulk_selected[]']").is(":checked");
//or...
return $("input[name='bulk_selected[]']:checked").length;
```

[`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) will return `true` is *any* of the elements match the selector.  Or a bit faster version:

```
return $("input[name='bulk_selected[]']").filter(function() { 
  return this.checked; 
}).length > 0;
```